# Strange Stretching of Text

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xib

I am making an app which has a menu using Xcode 5. For the button to the menu I set the title to this character: `≡`. I used the system font at size 30 to make it look good. This is what the top of the view looks like in the .xib file:

[image: top of view in .xib file]

The problem occurs when I run the program in the iOS Simulator (ios7). The text gets strangely stretched and no longer looks the way I want it to:

[image: top of view in ios simulator]

I was wondering why this stretching is occurring and if there is a possible way to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

What version of iOS is the simulator running? Just looking at the battery icon, it looks like it may be iOS 7. So perhaps you are getting differences as a result of different iOS.

Comment: Isn't the system font different for iOS 6 vs 7 :)

Comment: @deanWombourne Yes but shouldn't Xcode 5 show .xibs in ios7 format with those system fonts. Another interesting thing I recently ran this on my phone (ios7) and it looks perfect. Is this some apple bug in the ios7 simulator?

Comment: I code in 4.6 right now as I really do not like iOS 7. But what I’m wondering is if you can have xib’s in iOS 6 but run the simulator in 7. What version does your simulator indicate it is running?